# ANTLR returns empty tree and grun says it can't load Python3 as lexer or parser

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, antlr, antlr4

I want to build Python3 parser with antlr using python3. What I have done:

1. Downloaded antlr-4.7.1-complete.jar
2. sudo pip3 install antlr4-python3-runtime
3. export CLASSPATH=".:/usr/local/lib/antlr-4.7.1-complete.jar:$CLASSPATH"
4. downloaded grammar from official antlr grammars: https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/python3-py
5. Build parser and lexer:

---

```
>alias antlr4='java -Xmx500M -cp "/usr/local/lib/antlr-4.7.1-     complete.jar:$CLASSPATH" org.antlr.v4.Tool'
>alias grun='java org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig'
>antlr4 -Dlanguage=Python3 Python3.g4 //this generated Python3Lexer and Parser and other files
>grun Python3 file_input --tokens test.py
Can't load Python3 as lexer or parser
```

---

This is strange as this problem usually appears when CLASSPATH is wrongly set, but it is right.

6.tested a rule (file_input/single_input) for example for string: `import foo`/ `def f` (anything like `keyword _ smth`) I got this:

> line 1:6 extraneous input ' ' expecting NAME
>    line 1:10 mismatched input '' expecting {NEWLINE, ';'}

This is also strange as I have downloaded grammar from antlr repository and it works for other people

7. My `main.py` tries to get tree from test file but tree is always empty:

---

```
def main():
    input = FileStream("test.py")
    lexer = Python3Lexer(input)
    stream = CommonTokenStream(lexer)
    parser = Python3Parser(stream)
    tree = parser.file_input()
    print(tree)
```

So, the problem is that my parser and lexer are not working. I tried to do it with my classmate Lexer and Parser (both work for him) for Python3 generated same way and it still didn't work.